# Looking to identify an unusual type of solitaire

Tags: identify-this-game, variants, solitaire

I went to college in the 1980s and someone there showed me an unusual way to play solitaire that I've played ever since. This game uses one standard deck of cards [no jokers].

Two rows of cards are dealt into stacks, each stack having 4 cards, and the cards are all face down. The top row is for cards numbered 2 through 8 and the bottom row is for cards numbered 9 and 10 and the jack, king, and queen face cards. The last stack the ace stack and this is placed to the bottom left of the two rows. Play starts with the ace stack; the first card on the stack is turned over and then place under the corresponding stack, i.e.; if a 2 is turned over this card is placed under the 2 stack an the first card on the 2 stack is turned over. The game is won when the last card turned over is the fourth ace.

Any help with the name of this variant is appreciated; I've been playing this game for decades and have no idea what to call it!

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like it's equivalent to [Clock Patience](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clock_Patience), but with a less space-consuming layout and using the aces as the starter pile rather than the kings.  I've also seen it referred to as "[Travellers](https://www.bvssolitaire.com/rules/travellers.htm)".